# What does the arguments mean in PDFBox Matrix

Tags: java, apache, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I've followed this example [Create landscape PDF](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/CreateLandscapePDF.java?view=markup) and it works fine. I would now like to move the 0,0 reference from the lower left corner to the top left corner. To do that I need change `contentStream.transform(new Matrix(0, 1, -1, 0, pageWidth, 0));`. I've had a look at the documentation for [PDFBox Matrix](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/util/Matrix.html#Matrix(float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float)) which specfices the arguments for `Matrix` like below.

```
public Matrix(float a,
      float b,
      float c,
      float d,
      float e,
      float f)
Creates a matrix with the given 6 elements.
```

But it doesn't tell me what the 6 different arguments/elements do. I guess one has do with rotation and two for moving the reference in X and Y direction. Where can I find a document that describes the arguments?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Where can I find a document that describes the arguments?

The document to look for is the PDF specification (ISO 32000-1) in combination with some Linear Algebra 101.

> A transformation matrix in PDF shall be specified by six numbers, usually in the form of an array containing six elements. In its most general form, this array is denoted [*a b c d e f*]; it can represent any linear transformation from one coordinate system to another.

*(section 8.3.3 - Common Transformations)*

The meaning is explained shortly thereafter:

> PDF represents coordinates in a two-dimensional space. The point (*x, y*) in such a space can be expressed in vector form as [*x y* 1]. The constant third element of this vector (1) is needed so that the vector can be used with 3-by-3 matrices in the calculations described below.
>
> The transformation between two coordinate systems can be represented by a 3-by-3 transformation matrix written as follows:
>
> [image: a b 0 c d 0 e f 1]
>
> Because a transformation matrix has only six elements that can be changed, in most cases in PDF it shall be specified as the six-element array [*a b c d e f*].
>
> Coordinate transformations shall be expressed as matrix multiplications:
>
> [image: transformation]

*(section 8.3.4 - Transformation Matrices)*

Thus, when a transformation [*a b c d e f*] is currently set and you draw something using coordinates (*x, y*), it will appear at coordinates (*x', y'*) where

[image: transformation as coordinate-wise equations]

Commonly used transformation types are:

> - Translations shall be specified as [1 0 0 1 *t<sub>x</sub> t<sub>y</sub>*], where *t<sub>x</sub>* and *t<sub>y</sub>* shall be the distances to translate the origin of the coordinate system in the horizontal and vertical dimensions, respectively.
> - Scaling shall be obtained by [*s<sub>x</sub>* 0 0 *s<sub>y</sub>* 0 0]. This scales the coordinates so that 1 unit in the horizontal and vertical dimensions of the new coordinate system is the same size as *s<sub>x</sub>* and *s<sub>y</sub>* units, respectively, in the previous coordinate system.
> - Rotations shall be produced by [cos(*q*) sin(*q*) -sin(*q*) cos(*q*) 0 0], which has the effect of rotating the coordinate system axes by an angle *q* counter clockwise.
> - Skew shall be specified by [1 tan(*a*) tan(*b*) 1 0 0], which skews the *x* axis by an angle *a* and the *y* axis by an angle *b*.

*(section 8.3.3 - Common Transformations)*

If you want a combined transformation, simply multiply the matrices in the appropriate order.

Comment: thank you for a very detailed answer. Finally I know what I should use the linear algebra I learned at university for :).